# Symfony - Fullcalendar event description undefined

Tags: javascript, symfony, fullcalendar, undefined, fullcalendar-4

I have a controller that gets data from database and turns it in events for fullcalendar, when I display a modal clicking in one of this events, it shows that description and email are undefined.

[Image of modal undefined fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQddt.png)

But in XHR I can see that im receiving all the data from the controller.

[Image of XHR GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eye0h.png)

Modal:

```
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade" style="z-index: 9999;>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

            <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">         

        <p id="ev_start" class="modal-body"></p>
        <p id="ev_end" class="modal-body"></p>
        <p id="ev_mail" class="modal-body"></p>
        <p id="ev_desc" class="modal-body"></p>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"><a id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Javascript:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    var eventObj = info.event;      


      alert('Clicked ' + eventObj.title + ' with id: ' + eventObj.id + eventObj.description);

        $('#modalTitle').html(eventObj.title);
        $('#ev_titulo').html(eventObj.title);

        $('#ev_start').html('Fecha inicio: ' + eventObj.start);
        $('#ev_end').html('Fecha fin: ' + eventObj.end);
        $('#ev_desc').html('Descripcion: ' + eventObj.description);
        $('#ev_mail').html('Mail: ' + eventObj.mail);


        $('#fullCalModal').modal('show');

  },
```

---

Controller:

```
public function loadAction()
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $eventos = $em->getRepository('App:Evento')->findAll();

    $data = array();

    foreach ($eventos as $evento)
    {       
        $events['id'] = $evento->getId();
        $events['title'] = $evento->getTitle();
        $events['start'] = $evento->getBeginAt()->format('Y-m-d');;
        $events['end'] = $evento->getEndAt()->format('Y-m-d');;
        $events['color'] = $evento->getColor();
        $events['description'] = $evento->getDescription();
        $events['mail'] = $evento->getMail();
        array_push($data, $events);
    }

        return $this->json($data);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [event parsing documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) states that

> Every other non-standard prop will be transferred over to the
>   extendedProps hash in the Event Object.

Since `description` and `mail` are not standard event properties in fullCalendar (as listed in that documentation), then they will be placed under the "extendedProps" object in the final event object which fullCalendar creates based on the data it receives from your server.

Therefore in your `eventClick` code you should be able to write

```
$('#ev_desc').html('Descripcion: ' + eventObj.extendedProps.description);
$('#ev_mail').html('Mail: ' + eventObj.extendedProps.mail);
```

and populate the properties successfully into your modal.

P.S. This behaviour is also mentioned in the [event object documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) as well. If you have previously used fullCalendar version 3 or below, then this is a change from how these earlier versions worked.

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the answer so it turns green) - thanks :-)